# How do you save Pulumi const output to an aws s3 bucket (typescript)

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, pulumi

I'm writing [IaC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrastructure_as_code) to deploy [Amazon EKS](https://aws.amazon.com/eks/) in [Pulumi](https://www.pulumi.com/) + [typescript](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/languages/javascript/). I am using [GitHub Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions) as my CI/CD.

Currently I can create the EKS cluster via my pipeline with pulumi without issue but I have not figured out a clean way to acquire the resulting kubeconfig.

I can get the kubeconfig via the [frequently documented example](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/guides/crosswalk/aws/eks/#provisioning-a-new-eks-cluster) by exporting the cluster.kubeconfig value and then executing the stack output kubeconfig subcommand

```
# code snippet
export const kubeconfig = cluster.kubeconfig;

# command
pulumi stack output kubeconfig > kubeconfig.yml
```

As a current workaround, I am using this method to create the kubeconfig file in github actions, and then using an `aws s3` cli command to upload the file to s3.

I have already created a private s3 bucket with kms encryption in my pulumi iac and defined the kubeconfig output in my iac. Is there a way to write my pulumi typescript code to push the output directly to my s3 bucket without these intermediary steps?

UPDATE1: Current best effort brings me to:

```
const keksAdminBucket = new aws.s3.Bucket("keksAdminBucket", {acl: "private"});
const keksAdminBucketObject = new aws.s3.BucketObject("keksAdminBucketObject", {
    key: "kubeconfig",
    bucket: keksAdminBucket.id,
    source: new pulumi.asset.StringAsset(String(cluster.kubeconfig)),
    serverSideEncryption: "aws:kms",
});
```

This and variations on the theme result in errors like:

```
    index.ts(45,42): error TS2345: Argument of type 'Output<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Promise<string>'.
      Type 'OutputInstance<any>' is not assignable to type 'string | Promise<string>'.
        Type 'OutputInstance<any>' is missing the following properties from type 'Promise<string>': then, catch, [Symbol.toStringTag], finally
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `apply` method because `kubeconfig` is an `Output<string>` (or `Output<any>`?), not just a `string`:

```
const keksAdminBucketObject = new aws.s3.BucketObject("keksAdminBucketObject", {
    key: "kubeconfig",
    bucket: keksAdminBucket.id,
    source: cluster.kubeconfig.apply(s => new pulumi.asset.StringAsset(JSON.stringify(s))),
    serverSideEncryption: "aws:kms",
});
```

Learn more about outputs and apply in the [docs](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/inputs-outputs/).

Comment: I added a missing ```)``` and then ran the code. It ran clean, however the content of the ```kubeconfig``` file in the s3 bucket ended up being:
```[object Object]```

Comment: Okay, I didn't know your `kubeconfig` was an object not string. It makes sense now. I fixed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer ended up being:

```
const keksAdminBucket = new aws.s3.Bucket("keksAdminBucket", {acl: "private"});
const keksAdminBucketObject = cluster.kubeconfig.apply(
  (config) =>
    new aws.s3.BucketObject("keksAdminBucketObject", {
      key: "kubeconfig",
      bucket: keksAdminBucket.id,
      source: new pulumi.asset.StringAsset(JSON.stringify(config)),
      serverSideEncryption: "aws:kms",
    })
)
```

And I do not understand it well enough to explain why yet.

Comment: Creating resources in `apply` is discoraged: e.g., you will not see it in the initial preview. See my updated answer that should work better.